# how to limit the number  product  shows of the category?

Tags: php, magento

1,I  created a category which ID is 6,

2.In `cms–>manage page–>home` part i put this  `{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="6" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`

how to limit the number  product  shows of the category? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put `limit` parameter

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="6" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" limit = 9}}
```

Comment: the number shows 14 in the admin part, i put the picture on the question. why on the home page it only show 9 products. i can't set limit = 9 in the code. why?

Comment: i am sorry, it can't work.there is a $_columnCount = 4;  in list.phtml